# Write text in streaming video in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm looking for some solution to stream recorded videos safely to stop privacy making a streaming like website for a school for streaming I'm following this tutorial https://github.com/Abdisalan/blog-code-examples/tree/master/http-video-stream which works fine for me but can someone download video with this technique? if yes then any way or keywords which i can search for if user can't download video then stop the screen recording how can I print the particular text on random places in entirely video which can be the username or email of the student.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no way to prevent a determined user from downloading something like this. By definition they are already downloading the video to watch it. They could just point a camera at the computer screen or run a screen recorder or capture the raw stream.

Comment: Hmm so is there any way to write text while streaming the video on random place in entire video so if someone records it we can know about that students roll number or username or something like that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.